# Android coding string wrong (attribute is missing)

Tags: android, xml

Im verry new to coding, still learning the basics. While i was trying to finish the tutorial, i bumped into a problem, i was trying to make some "resources" then i got this error msg "attribute is missing the android namespace prefix" I've searched around on this website, couldn't found a solution. The problem is at line 16, 19, 22 and 25. If someone could help me, that would be fantastic!

Regards
Kristoffer

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <resources>

        <string name="edit_message" >Enter a message
        </string>

        <string name="button_send" >Send
        </string>

        <string name="action_settings" >Settings
        </string>

        <string name="title_activity_main" >MainActivity
        </string>
    </resources>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Move your resources code to string.xml file in value folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the below to `res/values/strings.xml` and remove them from your layout xml

```
<resources>
 <string name="edit_message" >Enter a message </string>
 <string name="button_send" >Send </string>
 <string name="action_settings" >Settings</string>
 <string name="title_activity_main" >MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to include string resources on a layout file. You should place your strings in the strings.xml file and then reference these strings using `@string/your_string_name`